# Adding FK constraints on multiple column in PHPMyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, foreign-keys

[image]

A Picture is worth thousand word. In the above picture we can add FK constraint 1-1, like I can reference UserId to another tables column but If the situation is like this ,

```
ALTER TABLE `userfrnd_source`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `userfrnd_source_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`userId`,`friendId`) 
  REFERENCES `user` (`userId`,`friendId`) 
  ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

How can I do this through PHPMyadmin, I know Using `SQL` we can do but with this tab is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As documented in the [FAQ](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/faq.html#what-is-currently-not-supported-in-phpmyadmin-about-innodb):

> #### 3.6 What is currently not supported in phpMyAdmin about InnoDB?
>
> In Relation view, having more than one index column in the foreign key.